# SQL: how to check palindrome of a string without using reverse function?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and I want to check whether the given string is a palindrome or not - but without using the `reverse` function.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `reverse()`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I'm just trying to achieve this without using the reverse function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. One of them is to check first and last character, slicing them if they're equal and continuing the process in a loop.

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @counter INT

SET @string = 'Your string'
SET @counter = LEN(@string)/2

WHILE (@counter > 0)
    BEGIN
    IF LEFT(@string,1) = RIGHT(@string,1)
        BEGIN
        SET @string = SUBSTRING(@string,2,len(@string)-2)
        SET @counter = @counter - 1
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        PRINT ('Given string is not a Palindrome')
        BREAK
        END
    END
IF(@counter = 0)
    PRINT ('Given string is a Palindrome')
```

Answer (score 2):

A select without loops

```
DECLARE @Test VARCHAR(100)

SELECT @Test = 'qwerewq' 


SELECT CASE WHEN LEFT(@Test, LEN(@Test)/2) =
    (
    SELECT '' + SUBSTRING(RIGHT(@Test, LEN(@Test)/2), number, 1)
    FROM master.dbo.spt_values
    WHERE type='P' AND number BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(@Test)/2
    ORDER BY number DESC
    FOR XML PATH('')
    )
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example using `LEFT` and `RIGHT`.  I use the @count variable to change position, then grab the left-most and right-most char:

```
DECLARE @mystring varchar(100) = 'redivider'
DECLARE @count int = 1

WHILE (@count < LEN(@mystring) / 2) AND @count <> 0
BEGIN
  IF (RIGHT(LEFT(@mystring, @count), 1) <> LEFT(RIGHT(@mystring, @count), 1))
  SET @count = 0
  ELSE SET @count += 1
END

SELECT CASE WHEN @count = 0
             THEN 'Not a Palindrome'
             ELSE 'Palindrome'
       END [Result]
```